# How to use a UITabBar with separate storyboards in iOS8/Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

So basically I have several storyboards that contain "reusable" content (like a form and some other things). I have another storyboard that has a UITabBarController with one tab that contains a TableViewController and a detail view, a second tab that opens a Settings view, and potentially a third button that opens the form (referenced earlier in my question) modally. My question is...how can I create this third tab within my Tab Bar Controller storyboard since the view that it opens resides in a separate storyboard (as in I can't drag a segue like is the normal process)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate a view controller programmatically from a storyboard by using the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method of the storyboard that defines that view controller.

To get an instance of your form, you may do something along the lines of this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourFormStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("formViewController") as! YourFormClass
```

You then populate the tab bar controller with its root views as you always have, laid out here in the Apple docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/

Comment: Right, I got all that working in other views, but my issue is..to create a third button (tab) in my tab bar controller view...doesn't the view it is linking to have to live in the same storyboard? Otherwise, how do I get a third button that just opens the modal (form) without dragging a segue to another view? (sorry if that question doesn't make sense, it does in my head, haha)

Comment: Ohhh...should I be using a "blank" navigation controller as the third root view that just opens the modal storyboard/view in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: That's one way to do it, definitely. You can also add any views that you want to the tab bar at runtime when the TabBarController itself loads. If you take a look at the docs, you simply pass the TabBarController an array of UIViewControllers you'd like it to display.